# Subtract Max and Min from same column

Tags: sql, oracle, date, subtraction

```
select 
      d.FK_SOCRD_ID,
      d.SUBJECT_NUMBER,
      c.PTLASTNAME || ', ' || c.PTFIRSTNAME as "Patient name",
      min(b.created) as Data Entry 1,
      max(b.created) as Data Entry 2,
      min(b.created) - max(b.created) 
        || ' days and '
        || TO_CHAR(to_date('01/01/2000', 'MM-DD-YYYY') 
                + (b.created - b.created), 'HH24:MI:SS' ) AS Diff
   FROM 
      CR_MDT a
         full outer join CR_MDT_VERIFY b
            on a.CR_MDT_ID = b.FK_CR_MDT_ID
         left join patient c
            on a.FK_SOCRD_ID = c.SOCRD_ID
            left join PT_STUDY d
               on c.SOCRD_ID = d.FK_SOCRD_ID
   where 
          a.CR_MDT_DT between TO_DATE('01/01/2017', 'mm/dd/yyyy') 
      and TO_DATE('12/31/2017', 'mm/dd/yyyy')
   group by 
      d.FK_SOCRD_ID,
      d.SUBJECT_NUMBER,
      c.PTLASTNAME,
      c.PTFIRSTNAME,
      b.created
```

How can I subtract the max(b.created) from min(b.created)? I'm stuck on this part:

```
|| TO_CHAR(to_date('01/01/2000', 'MM-DD-YYYY') 
        + (b.created - b.created), 'HH24:MI:SS' ) AS Diff
```

I need help on how to write the subtraction part since b.created max and min are from the same column.

Comment: I am using Oracle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what gave me the desired result:

SELECT  
d.FK_SOCRD_ID,
 
    d.SUBJECT_NUMBER,
 
        c.PTLASTNAME || ', ' || c.PTFIRSTNAME AS "Patient name",
 
        min(b.created) AS min_created, 
        max(b.created) AS max_created, 
        trunc(max(b.created)) - trunc(min(b.created)) || ' days' AS Diff
FROM CR_MDT a
FULL JOIN CR_MDT_VERIFY b
    ON a.CR_MDT_ID = b.FK_CR_MDT_ID
LEFT JOIN patient c
    ON c.SOCRD_ID = a.FK_SOCRD_ID
LEFT JOIN PT_STUDY d
    ON d.FK_SOCRD_ID = c.SOCRD_ID
WHERE a.CR_MDT_DT BETWEEN TO_DATE('01/01/2017', 'mm/dd/yyyy') AND TO_DATE
('12/31/2017', 'mm/dd/yyyy')
GROUP BY d.FK_SOCRD_ID, 
d.SUBJECT_NUMBER, 
c.PTLASTNAME, 
c.PTFIRSTNAME

Answer (score 0):

You can put that query in a subquery and do the subtraction outside:

```
SELECT *
    , max_created - min_created as date_difference
FROM
(
SELECT d.FK_SOCRD_ID
    , d.SUBJECT_NUMBER
    , c.PTLASTNAME || ', ' || c.PTFIRSTNAME AS "Patient name"
    , min(b.created) AS min_created
    , max(b.created) AS max_created
FROM CR_MDT a
FULL JOIN CR_MDT_VERIFY b
    ON a.CR_MDT_ID = b.FK_CR_MDT_ID
LEFT JOIN patient c
    ON c.SOCRD_ID = a.FK_SOCRD_ID
LEFT JOIN PT_STUDY d
    ON d.FK_SOCRD_ID = c.SOCRD_ID
WHERE a.CR_MDT_DT BETWEEN TO_DATE('01/01/2017', 'mm/dd/yyyy') AND TO_DATE('12/31/2017', 'mm/dd/yyyy')
GROUP BY d.FK_SOCRD_ID
    , d.SUBJECT_NUMBER
    , c.PTLASTNAME
    , c.PTFIRSTNAME
) subq
```

You might have to change the datediff function depending on the dbms you are using.

EDIT: I updated the date subtraction part now that i know you use Oracle.

Comment: I may be doing something wrong. I need help still. I'm getting the ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended.

I placed this at the end as a sub query: 
            min(b.created) - max(b.created) 
        || ' days and '
        || TO_CHAR(to_date('01/01/2000', 'MM-DD-YYYY') as Diff
order by created
        '

Comment: so we should be doing that subtraction not in the subquery but in the outside query. so can you try the updated query above ?

Comment: Sorry guys, getting the ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected error. I tried to change it to: SELECT *
,
max(created) - min(created) as date_difference to fix the issue but still get the same ora-00923 error. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: So I finally got it to show how I want but now I am still stuck with the Diff column displaying '01/01/2000' after the number of days. How can I correct this?  'SELECT d.FK_SOCRD_ID
    , d.SUBJECT_NUMBER
    , c.PTLASTNAME || ', ' || c.PTFIRSTNAME AS "Patient name"
    , min(b.created) AS min_created
    , max(b.created) AS max_created
, trunc(max(b.created)) - trunc(min(b.created)) || ' days'
  || TO_CHAR(to_date('01/01/2000', 'MM-DD-YYYY')) AS Diff'

Comment: @idkfa.bfg2 i recommend you create a sample schema in sql fiddle so we can see some sample data and see why the errors are happening. http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: nvm got it:  SELECT d.FK_SOCRD_ID
    , d.SUBJECT_NUMBER
    , c.PTLASTNAME || ', ' || c.PTFIRSTNAME AS "Patient name"
    , min(b.created) AS min_created
    , max(b.created) AS max_created
, trunc(max(b.created)) - trunc(min(b.created)) || ' days'
 AS Diff

Answer (score 0):

You can use `floor()`, leave only fractional part of difference and convert it to `hh24:mi:ss`, like here:

```
select id, mx, mn, floor(diff) ||' days and '|| 
       to_char(trunc(sysdate) + diff - floor(diff), 'hh24:mi:ss') diff
  from (select id, max(created) mx, min(created) mn, 
               max(created) - min(created) diff
          from test group by id)
```

Test data:

```
create table test (id number(3), created date);
insert into test values (1, timestamp '2017-09-12 01:00:00');
insert into test values (1, timestamp '2017-11-05 11:24:17');
insert into test values (1, timestamp '2017-12-15 13:42:05');
insert into test values (2, timestamp '2017-01-05 11:00:00');
insert into test values (2, timestamp '2017-06-05 23:12:56');
```

Result:

```
  ID  MX                   MN                   DIFF
----  -------------------  -------------------  ---------------------
   1  2017-12-15 13:42:05  2017-09-12 01:00:00  94 days and 12:42:05
   2  2017-06-05 23:12:56  2017-01-05 11:00:00  151 days and 12:12:56
```

Comment: I'm getting ORA-00904: "DIFF": invalid identifier error.

Comment: If You copy and paste my query You get no error. So You missed something, probably column alias. Follow this logic and You'll get what You need.